# Custom string representation of a Python Class property

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, class

I am defining a Class with several properties, most of which are `int` or `float` and for each I need to setup a specific string representation, is there an equivalent of `__str__` or `__repr__` for properties ?

UPDATE: to clarify, I'd like to have a custom string representation for my `int` and `float` values such as '  022' or ' 3.27 ' related to the actual values, not just a static string for any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own property object and override the intended methods. Here is an example:

```
In [48]: class MyProperty(property):
    ...:     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...:         super()
    ...:     def __str__(self):
    ...:         return "custom_name"
    ...:     

In [49]: 

In [49]: class C:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self._x = None
    ...: 
    ...:     @MyProperty
    ...:     def x(self):
    ...:         """I'm the 'x' property."""
    ...:         return self._x
    ...: 
    ...:     @x.setter
    ...:     def x(self, value):
    ...:         self._x = value
    ...: 
    ...:     @x.deleter
    ...:     def x(self):
    ...:         del self._x
    ...:         

In [50]: 

In [50]: print(C.x)
custom_name
```

As another example you can find the callable object within args and preserve it for later in order to be able to access the name or ant other attribute of it that you're interested in.

```
In [78]: class MyProperty(property):
    ...:     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...:         self.__inp = next(i for i in args if isinstance(i, types.FunctionType)) 
    ...:         super()
    ...:     
    ...:     def __str__(self):
    ...:         return f"property name is : {self.__inp.__name__}"
```

Then:

```
In [80]: print(C.x)
property name is : x
```

Comment: Does this mean I need to setup as many Classes as different string representations ? Can the strings be a formatting of the number (dependent on the value) ?

Comment: @YeO If you get the value and call the `str`, `repr` or any other attribute of that value if will act based on the way those attributes are defined for that object but if you want to call those attributes of the property functions and get a representation of the value there might be some hacky ways like getting the function constant from function `__code__` object. But it's not a reliable way and I don't see any use for that.

Comment: Your updated code gives me an error "NameError: name 'types' is not defined"

Comment: Scrath my last, I added `import types`